# Static library with dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, static-libraries

`e.exe` is linked against my custom static library, `c.lib`, which uses Win32 API defined in `w.dll`. `w.dll` is located in C:\Windows\System32 and its import library is `w.lib`, located in Windows SDK directory. Shell `w.lib` be listed as *Additional Dependency* in `c.lib` or `e.exe` project? (`e.exe` builds successfully in both cases.) What is the best practice and why? I guess `e.exe` should not know about `w.lib`.

`c.lib` is intended to be shared among a group of developers only (not to be shipped to customers).

**TEST**: I used VS2008 and dumpbin utility to test both cases and here are results:

- Case 1: `w.lib` added as *Additional Dependency* in `c.lib` project.

`dumpbin /archivemembers c.lib` output lists both offsets in `w.dll` and .obj files from `c.lib` project as Archive members.

- Case 2: `w.lib` not added as *Additional Dependency* in `c.lib` but in `e.exe` project:

This time, dumpbin output contains only .obj files of `c.lib` and the size of `c.lib` is smaller than in Case 1

(`c.lib` was added as *Additional Dependency* in `w.exe` project in both cases.)

**NOTE**: I used `w.lib` and `w.dll` here as fictional, generic names for Windows libraries but they could be e.g. Userenv.lib and Userenv.dll or Version.lib and Version.dll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what creating an archive and an import archive does.

Creating an archive, as you've rightly surmised in comments, creates a unified file containing compiled .objs. Now, this can contain any code you like, including but not limited to dynamic calls to libraries. An import library is a library that contains an obj that exclusively makes such calls, the idea being that by importing it, your exe can find the appropriate symbols (they must be in the executable you create).

The process of creating `c.lib` from `w.lib` simply extracts `w.lib`'s objects and appends them to the collection of objects in `c.lib`. In effect, `c.lib` becomes an import library + code.

Do I think you should do this? Not really - it might lead to confusion as to what `e.exe` depends on; I think you should explicitly make this visible rather than trying to hide it. That said, that's a recommendation only, not a rule.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. My initial presumption was wrong - I thought it was desirable exe not to be aware of lib's dependencies but now when I look at it from *import library + code* point of view it makes sense to let the exe know what its code (which actually includes code from static lib) depends on.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer.  Is it not common to build libraries on top of libraries?  Any extended library would be considered "import library + code".  I would think it's better practice to hide the details of the library being built upon.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are not linked, so any project that uses a .lib also needs its dependencies.

Basically the .lib are "copied" to your exe during linking.

If you want to avoid your users to explicity link againts w.lib, transforms c.lib in a dll, dlls are linked and you do not need their dependencies during build.

Comment: I understand that `link.exe` does not resolve external references but just zips a set of `obj` files in order to create static library. My question was about dependencies in compile time - Case 1 shows that `e.exe` did not know about `w.lib` at all. Of course, `w.dll` must be present in runtime.