# How do I create a C++ library that can be used independently of its dependencies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, linker

Basically, I wrote a C++ library which has a number of dependencies. They are:

- GNU Scientific Library for Windows
- GLEW
- STD (std::vector, is this even a dependency?)

I would like to be able to generate, using Visual Studio 2010, a library from this code. I would like to be able to create a new Win32 Console Application, reference the library and work with it. I don't want it to be necessary to have this new console application reference the library's dependencies as well.

I'm unsure if what I'm after is even possible. Should I create a dynamic or a static library? How should I link to it? These are sub-questions that come to mind, but I think I'm missing the big picture here.

Therefore my question is: How do I create a C++ library that can be used indepentently of its dependencies?

Comment: If the idea is to come up with a single binary that you can deploy on any Windows platform, then just compile statically.  You'll still need to include `mingw32.dll` though.

Comment: This is more or less a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646937/static-library-with-dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create wrapper functions and classes that reference these libraries? Also these other libraries have to be statically linked or if they are linked dynamically, you will have to deploy the DLLs with your application!

If all else fail, use UPX? :-) to create a single binary.

Comment: In the end I decided to work with CMake to handle configuration duties for me. I misunderstood the way compilation and linkage works in C++ environments and asked the wrong question. I'm accepting your answer though because it would have been the correct answer if I had been able to assess my own situation better. Thanks :)