# How to find out the list of DLLs dependent on a LIB file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll, static-libraries

Since my project is very huge, while debugging I manually disable the loading of all modules in Visual Studio, and then enable **only** those DLLs in which I have to debug. This works as expected.

But since the list of modules in Visual Studio doesn't contain LIB files, how can I debug the code inside a particular static library?

Is there an option to see the list of DLLs which are linked to a library file **(.lib)** ?

Comment: Since you have the `static-libraries` tag I assume you only mean these by calling them out as `.lib` (and not DLL import libraries). Static libraries are not loaded during runtime, but are incorporated at link time. So, as it stands, your question makes little sense.

Comment: Then how do you debug a static lib code? I see that debugging a static-lib is possible when "Load symbols of all modules" is enabled! I want to debug the static-lib by loading symbols of minimum number of DLLs. Is that possible? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: `Is there an option to see the list of DLLs which are linked to a library file (.lib) ? ` a static library has no dependencies that could be listed. Dependencies (read "unresolved external symbols") are resolved at link time and could then be either from other static libraries or from DLLs, or simply `.obj` files or the "main executable" itself.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647512/21567) is also relevant.

Comment: @Christian.K `the "main executable" itself` this is what worked for me. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static library isn't linked with anything. It is just a bag of
object files that you offer to the linker from which to pick the
ones it needs to define the external symbols in your program.
It extracts the object files that it needs from the static library
and embeds them into your program.

So, suppose `abc.lib` contains object files `a.obj`, `b.obj`, `c.obj`. You build a program `prog` by linking `main.obj` and `abc.lib`. `main.obj` needs something defined in `a.obj` plus something defined in `c.obj` but nothing defined in `b.obj`. Then `prog` is exactly the same as if you had simply linked the  three object files `main.obj`, `a.obj`, `c.obj` and not mentioned `abc.lib` at all.

Now `a.obj` or `c.obj` might call functions externally defined in
one or more DLLs. Maybe `main.obj` calls functions that are externally
defined in the same or other DLLs. `prog` will have to be linked with
those DLLs - no more and no less. The DLL dependencies of `main.obj`
+ `a.obj` + `c.obj` are the DLL dependencies of your `prog`, and vice versa.
There aren't any that are concealed by linking `abc.lib` rather than `a.obj` and `c.obj`.

Comment: Found success by loading symbols of only `prog.exe`, and thus it helped me to keep the visual studio application lighter while debugging. By this way I avoided loading all the other DLLs which takes lot of time. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do as test, is to create a dummy dll using the static lib and then have a look of the dll with dependency walker (or with vs linking process) and find the linked dlls.